# How to display a ForeignKey value?

Tags: python, django

I have got a model PurchaseOrder and Orderline. I can display all values from the OrderLine model, but can`t display the value assigned to the PurchaseOrder model. I have tried many combinations but they do not seem to work. Any ideas why?

**models.py**

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model): 
  po_number = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)

class OrderLine(models.Model):
    purchaseorder = models.ForeignKey(PurchaseOrder,related_name="has_lines",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_item = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Line")
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def detail_order(request, purchaseorder_id):
    purchaseorder = PurchaseOrder.objects.get(pk=purchaseorder_id)
    orderlines = OrderLine.objects.all()
    purchaseorders = PurchaseOrder.objects.all()
    context = {
               
                'purchaseorder': purchaseorder,
                'purchaseorders': purchaseorders,
                'orderlines': orderlines,                           
            } 
    return render(request, 'accounting/orders/order_detail.html', context)
```

**order_detail.html**

```
<tbody>
     
         {% for orderline in purchaseorder.orderlines_set.all %}
         <tr>
            <td>{{ orderline.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ orderline.order_item }}</td>      
         </tr> 
         {% endfor %}
                                                           
</tbody>
```

Comment: What happens when you do this? You should just be able to loop over like that, but you need to do `{% for orderline in purchaseorder.orderlines_set.all() %}` (notice the parentheses)

Comment: Also, in your view you want to do `purchaseorder = PurchaseOrder.objects.select_related('orderlines_set').get(pk=purchaseorder_id)`. This will ensure you're not doing another queries per orderline

Comment: When adding `.all()`, I`ve got the following error: Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'purchaseorder.orderlines_set.all()'

Comment: When adding `purchaseorder = PurchaseOrder.objects.select_related('orderlines_set').get(pk=purchaseorder_id)`, I have the following error: `Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'orderlines_set'. Choices are: (none)`

Comment: do you try to do it like this - `purchaseorder.has_lines.all`?

Comment: Nice one, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `related_name` parameter to your `ForeignKey` it means that you override the "backward" relation alias and then you couldn't use alias like `<model-name-in-lower-case_set>` you must use that value which set in `related_name` parameter.

Read more on [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).